# Discordjs how to find user then add role

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a web app where the user can submit a form and after they do I want to grant them a role on my discord.

on Nodejs I have this code:

```
discordClient.users.fetch('1222333444').roles.add('123456789');
```

but I get:

```
Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

I tried multiple ways to do it but none of them worked unfortunately, the all use `discordClient.on('message'`

Which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that way in v12:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("guildid");
const member = guild.members.cache.get("memberid")
member.roles.add("roleid");
```

Comment: guild is coming as undefined here

Comment: You're probably typing an invalid guild id, a guild id is id of the server. Right click on server icon at left bar and get the id from there.

Comment: Yes I am using the guild id here but it's still undefined. Note that my bot is only being used in one server.

Comment: nvm I found my mistake, sorry. I was using my test bot.

Comment: hmm... now it says Cannot read property 'add' of undefined for member.roles.add('roleid')